# Entity framework 3.5 "Find" method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5

My app is stuck with win XP, I must convert it from EF 6 to EF 3.5 to compatible with net 3.5
In EF 5.x, I have

```
MyEntity db = new MyEntity();
int id = 1;
MyClass a = db.MyClasses.Find(id);
```

But in the old version ef 3.5, I can't find anything like that

Comment: It's was introduced in [EF 5.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). You can use `FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `DbSet<T>.Find(id)` method was introduced in [Entity Framework 5.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) for DbContext, so it naturally is not available to you here.

That said, considering that early EF was built upon it's Linq 2 SQL predecessor, there's no reason you can't query your context directly.

```
MyEntity db = new MyEntity();
int id = 1;
var result = db.MyClasses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

You can find Entity Framework 3.5 documentation of all available methods on [MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb918914%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)